# Why did my question about Visual Studio and CPU cores getting close votes?

Tags: discussion

I am curious to know why my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636036/can-visual-studio-2019-enterprise-use-extra-cpu-cores-if-you-have-more-than-4-co) about Visual Studio and CPU cores is getting close votes. My guess because it's not a pure programming question. Not all SO questions have to be programming questions. Related to programming, related to programming tools.. etc should be OK.
Also not leaving comments on the reason is not very helpful.

Comment: It asks for judgement on the part of anyone answering and thus it is an opinion based question.

Comment: It reads like a hardware recommendation question to me. This would be off-topic on SO. Also, compile time will depend on a lot of factors, not only on the number of CPU cores. Your question, btw, does not have any close votes at the moment.

Comment: Where's the opinion or hardware recommendation? It's asking if VS is able to use the increased number of cores.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: There are no close votes to your question here. Are you confusing down-votes with close-votes?

Comment: @bdl I am aware there are other factors. I am asking about cores also. It's not a mutual exclusive thing. I meant downvotes. Well now it's getting down and close votes because of the exposure my question got from here. Thanks guys!

Comment: Downvotes on main question are necessary as you don't explain how just looking at "build and run" options is not enough... or what results of https://www.bing.com/search?q=vs+mulitcore+build fail to show... (that's from people who read title only, body of the post on main is completely hardware reco)

Comment: @Alexei Why should I mention 'build and run' if I don't know about it or don't remember it? People ask questions because they aren't aware of certain types of information. Otherwise SO is good only for the most obscure stuff.

Comment: I have deleted the SO question because it's just collecting downvotes and then put on hold. I am not interested in any more answers or opinions at this point.

Answer (score 11):

Your question asks users to judge whether some (not really specified) hardware will give better compile times in Visual Studio. On one hand, this asks for opinions since compile time depends on a lot of factors, not all of the hardware related. On the other hand, even if the question wouldn't be opinion based, it basically asks for a hardware recommendation.

If you're really just interested in whether VS2019 will use all your cores, then go on and ask for that. It's also fine to ask how to enable VS to use a specific number of cores for compilation. But please don't asks users if this will result in better speed, ...

Comment: I personally don't think that asking whether VS will use more cores is appropriate for SO - clearly one looked at the "Build and run option" and read [corresponding help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-dialog-box-projects-and-solutions-build-and-run?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Projects.Build_and_Run);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019) to know the answer... I don't see how one would be able to ask non-opinion based question after that.

Comment: You're assuming too much. You're assuming all developers read all the reference material and documentation and remember everything they read. You're assuming everyone should know all the permutations of search keywords and how they are used. Is that case, a ton of SO questions shouldn't be in SO. This is not RTFM question.  It's a VS related question because it's related to its functionality. Explain why this question is OK but mine is not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457103/will-a-hybrid-hard-drive-improve-visual-studio-compilation-times. Seems like opinion based if mine is one.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich That question was asked 9 years ago, when rules were different.

Comment: @ModusTollens I am pretty sure recommendation and opinion based questions were not accepted very early on. Probably when it started in 2008. Not that I consider my question as one.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich It is still a good example of why questions like that are not the best fit for SO: it manged to get only 1k views and 6 upvotes in 9 years. The accepted answer was upvoted as helpful by only 3 users.